# SWIG, C, Python - Ignoring NULL terminators when passing a char * to python

Tags: python, c, arrays, char, swig

Put quickly:
I want to send a full char * from a C module (build with SWIG) to a python callback function.

I can already do most of this BUT: my char array is just binary data and therefore contains 0s which is being seen as a NULL terminator in the C->Python conversion. Python only receives the bytes up until the first 0 rather than the full array.

In the swig documentation it specifically says that treating char * as binary data is possible with a typemap but doesn't say how. I've been playing with cstring.i (%cstring_output_withsize etc) but I am relatively new to SWIG and am out of my depth.

How do I tell SWIG to ignore the NULL terminator and use a size value instead when passing to python?

=========================================================

If you need more detail:

For a little background, I'm writing a very simple network packet format/transfer protocol for a 802.15.4 RF network. There are multiple architectures, languages and transceivers on the network so I'm writing my library to have a unified settable callback function allowing a small wrapper to be written on each platform that passes a buffer of bytes to the transciever using that host language.

Below are the key parts of the code.

```
//defined in Packets.h
void (*send_callback_ptr)(char * payload, uint8_t payload_length, uint16_t destination,  uint16_t sequence_no);

//a function to set the callback
void send_callback_set(void (*f)(char * payload_buffer, uint8_t payload_length, uint16_t destination,  uint16_t sequence_no))
{
    send_callback_ptr = f;
}


uint8_t send(uint16_t target, enum PACKET_TYPE type, void * packet_object) {
    char * payload_buffer = malloc(128); //max buffer size is 128
    uint8_t payload_length = 12;

    pack(target, type, packet_object, payload_buffer);

    uint16_t destination = target;
    uint16_t sequence_no = GLOBAL.hash++;

    send_callback_ptr(payload, payload_length, destination, sequence_no);
};
```

At the top is the callback and the callback-setting function. 'send' takes a target, a packet type and a packet object (void * so python can pass it a pointer to a PyObject). It then packs all the data into char * payload_buffer using 'pack()' (pack just uses a set of rules to pack a packet object into a byte array ready to send).

```
def py_callback(buffer, buffer_length, destination, seq_no):
    print buffer_length
    print "type:", type(buffer)
    print "length:", len(buffer)

    for i in range(len(buffer)):
        print i, '{:02X}'.format(ord(buffer[i]))

MyModule.send_callback_set(py_callback)
```

The python then looks like this which recieves the payload, payload_length etc from the call to send_callback_ptr at the end of the C function send().

In one example, the python callback function only receives 3 bytes when it should get 13 because the 4th byte in the array is a 0.

Comment: Hello @Mudf4ce Have you found a solution? I'm facing a similar problem as well.

Comment: I did, but boy was this a long time ago.. From what I remember moving to Python3 was a huge help as it better defines the difference between a text string and a byte string.

Comment: I'm looking over the code I was talking about at the time..

go here: http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html and search "char_to_bytes". There's a code block there which forces SWIG to handle byte strings properly.

There are a few other code blocks in my SWIG file that may or may not have been relevant to this fix.. see if the above helps and if not let me know and I'll have another look.